# WPF Combo box collection container displayed text

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding

I use CompositeCollection & CollectionContainer to provide a default value for a combo box, but the problem is that actual data is displayed as the class full path.

Is there a way to select a field in the class to represent it? So instead of `StMaryChurchAttendance.Models.Groups`, it will show a string property.

Here is the xaml:

```
<StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" DataContext="{Binding SelectionBarDataContext}" Name="SearchPanel">
    <Label>Group : </Label>
    <ComboBox  Name="SelectionBarGroupsComboBox">
        <ComboBox.Resources>
            <CompositeCollection x:Key="CompositeCollection">
                <CollectionContainer Collection="{Binding Source={x:Reference SearchPanel}, Path=DataContext.Groups }" />
            </CompositeCollection>
        </ComboBox.Resources>
        <ComboBox.ItemsSource>
            <CompositeCollection>
                <ComboBoxItem Name="AllGroupItem" IsSelected="True">All Groups</ComboBoxItem>
                <CollectionContainer  Collection="{Binding Source={StaticResource CompositeCollection}}" />
            </CompositeCollection>
        </ComboBox.ItemsSource>
    </ComboBox>
</StackPanel>
```

[image: Example of problem]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually, this works:

```
<ComboBox  
    DisplayMemberPath="WhateverPropertyYouWant"
    Name="SelectionBarGroupsComboBox">
```

Replace `WhateverPropertyYouWant` with the property you want to display -- some property of `StMaryChurchAttendance.Models.Group`. Don't use a binding. Just type the name of the property between the quotation marks.

But you've got a mix of different stuff in there, so it's not going to work this time. Here's another option: Create an implicit `DataTemplate` for your `Group` class, that's only visible within the `ComboBox`. The `ComboBox` will use that to display `Groups`, without affecting anything else.

```
<ComboBox  
    Name="SelectionBarGroupsComboBox">
<ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate 
        xmlns:models="clr-namespace:StMaryChurchAttendance.Models"
        DataType="models:Group">
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" />
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
    <ComboBox.Resources>
        <CompositeCollection x:Key="CompositeCollection">
            <CollectionContainer Collection="{Binding Source={x:Reference SearchPanel}, Path=DataContext.Groups}" />
        </CompositeCollection>


    </ComboBox.Resources>
    <ComboBox.ItemsSource>
        <CompositeCollection>
            <ComboBoxItem Name="AllGroupItem" IsSelected="True">All Groups</ComboBoxItem>
            <CollectionContainer  Collection="{Binding Source={StaticResource CompositeCollection}}" />
        </CompositeCollection>
    </ComboBox.ItemsSource>
</ComboBox>
```

Comment: I believe it's `DisplayMemberPath` not `DisplayMemberName` .

Comment: This solves the problem,but introduces another one as I select the static value (first item), nothing is displayed at all. As it's string and doesn't have the property I specify

Comment: What's the name of the property you want to display?

Comment: The property is `Name`

Comment: @ShadyAtef Thanks. Just updated my answer with a solution that I think should work -- let me know if it has trouble iwth the `models` namespace I defined there.

Comment: I have changed your answer a little bit, 
I simply set `ComboBox.ItemTemplate` to your template and it worked

Comment: Awesome. I thought that wouldn't work with your extra item, but if it does, that's great.

Comment: Yeah, but please accept the edit, to let it be shown.

Comment: @ShadyAtef Done! Sorry, I misunderstood -- I thought you just meant you changed it on your end. I approved the edit.

Answer (score 0):

The way it is set in Ed Plunkett's answer caused binding errors for me, so here is how I solved it. I also used a `DataTemplate`, but I set it so that the `DataTemplate` gets implicitly set rather than explicitly. Perhaps this has to do with the fact that I put a `Separator` in the `ComboBox`.

First, make sure to set the namespace where the type resides

```
xmlns:models="clr-namespace:StMaryChurchAttendance.Models"
```

Then, set a `DataTemplate` for this type.

```
<ComboBox Name="SelectionBarGroupsComboBox">
    <ComboBox.Resources>
        <CompositeCollection x:Key="CompositeCollection">
            <CollectionContainer Collection="{Binding Source={x:Reference SearchPanel}, Path=DataContext.Groups}" />
        </CompositeCollection>
        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type models:Group}">
            TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </ComboBox.Resources>
    <ComboBox.ItemsSource>
        <CompositeCollection>
            <ComboBoxItem Name="AllGroupItem" IsSelected="True">All Groups</ComboBoxItem>
            <CollectionContainer  Collection="{Binding Source={StaticResource CompositeCollection}}" />
        </CompositeCollection>
    </ComboBox.ItemsSource>
</ComboBox>
```

The `DataTemplate` will be used whenever an object of type Group is bound. Otherwise, it will simply be ignored.